# Tata Photon 3g ZTE MF190 detected in Ubuntu 13.04 but not connected

Tags: usb-modem, 3g, zte

I'm using ubuntu 13.04.

Earlier i used Huawei 2g internet dongle which worked fine.

Recently I got TATA PHOTON 3g dongle which in ZTE MF190 model, it gets recognized and appears in my network panel on the top right corner but does not get connect.

I already tried configuration through mobile broadband methoed.

I'm unable to install wvdial offline.

I appreciate any Resolution or Suggestion towards the same!!!

Comment: Hey Rony can you please write step step by instructions that you did please , i tried to connect in many ways but couldnt do it ! My PC is detecting the device but i am having difficulty setting it up ..and how to execute the script Sakis3g ?

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded Sakis3g from http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-n4n0/files/sakis3g.tar.gz/download and executed the script on the terminal.Followed the connection steps guided by the script and able to connect internet now through ZTE MF190 USB modem distributed by TATA PHOTON 3G - Thanks

Comment: Just a question, how does it now show up with `sudo lshw -c network`?

Comment: *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 20:7c:8f:63:30:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list

Comment: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:90500000-9050ffff

Comment: *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:6a:8a:3d:cc:e2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

Comment: configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.128 firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:90400000-9040ffff memory:90410000-9041ffff memory:90450000-904507ff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: 02:05:bb:2f:4f:a2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=qmi_wwan driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=WWAN/QMI device link=no multicast=yes

Comment: @jeroen This is how output appears, for the command that you've suggested to shoot.Though i'm using through Gnome PPP currently but still i'd prefer if any solution can fix the issue with network manager. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed steps, also the information that you added in comments put it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed dongle, you in fact added a second nic (network interface controller). The logical name of your first nic wil probably have been `wlan0`, the second nic will then have been named `wlan1`, the third nic `wlan2` and so on. Connect the dongle you wish to use, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command: `sudo lshw -c network`. In the output check the logical name under the header Wireless interface. Now in your `networkmanager` change the logical name of the interface accordingly.

Comment: let me first thank you for your time and effort to answer this.After running the advised command i find below result:
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 20:7c:8f:63:30:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless. Which is the only wlan.